# How do I draw a grid of squares in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm working on a visual [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) program for Cocoa. The main view, of course, is basically a grid of square tiles that change color between black and white as the algorithm progresses, but I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to draw and manage this grid of squares.

My initial idea was to have each tile be a subclass of NSView. Drawing would be pretty simple: just fill it in black if it's alive, white if it's dead. But I'm not sure how to lay it out in a window; laying it out in Interface Builder as individual NSViews (and setting up the IB outlets for each one) seems tedious. I could position them programmatically, but that seems tedious, too (especially since I'd like to have a bit of space between each tile).

I remembered that NSMatrix was expressly designed to work with an array (or grid) of interface objects, so I figured I could just create an NSMatrix of my NSView subclass. The problem is, it seems you can only create an NSMatrix of NSControls. My custom tile view isn't really a *control* per se, since it won't need to accept mouse tracking events or the like, but I figured I could fake it and use it just for drawing (and just ignore any events).

Of course, if you're using a whole bunch of the same type of NSControl, it's best to use NSCell to do the drawing, but NSCell seems to be more geared towards drawing text- or image-based controls; I don't see a simple way to just draw a rect black or white.

I'm leaning towards abusing an NSControl subclass to do the drawing, and skipping out on associating an NSCell with that, but I wondered if there's a better way or something I haven't thought of yet.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in a previous project by using a matrix of custom `buttonCells`. I added a `backgroundColor` property to the button cell, so I could get a colored background on a cell with no border (which isn't possible with the standard cell types). Here is the subclass of `NSButtonCell` that I made:

```
@interface RDButtonCell : NSButtonCell <NSCoding> 

@property (retain) NSColor *selectedColor;
@property (retain) NSColor *backgroundColor;

-(id)initWithRGBAlpha:(NSArray *)rgbAlpha;


@implementation RDButtonCell

-(id)initWithRGBAlpha:(NSArray *)rgbAlpha {
    if (self = [super init]) {
    NSColor *color = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:[rgbAlpha[0]doubleValue]
                                               green:[rgbAlpha[1]doubleValue] 
                                                blue:[rgbAlpha[2]doubleValue] 
                                               alpha:[rgbAlpha[3]doubleValue]];
    [self setBackgroundColor:color];
    [self setTitle:@""];
    [self setBordered:NO];
    [self setTag:0];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) setState:(NSInteger)value {
    if (value == 1) {
        self.backgroundColor = self.selectedColor;
        [super setState:value];
    }else {
        self.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;
        [super setState:value];
    }
}


-(void) setBackgroundColor:(NSColor *)color {
    _backgroundColor = color;
    _selectedColor = [color colorWithAlphaComponent:.75];
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [super encodeWithCoder:encoder];
    [encoder encodeObject:_backgroundColor forKey:@"bColor"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    _backgroundColor = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"bColor"];
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to host a CALayer in your view and create a CALayer for every cell (each cell layer being a sublayer of your view's layer). Then just set the layer's background color.

Comment: Interesting. Your suggestion led me to a blog post (http://skuggdev.wordpress.com/2008/10/01/calayer-grid-with-caconstraintlayoutmanager/) that gives some insight on what I want to do.

Comment: I had to build a heat map view recently. I didn't use layers (should have) but just a single NSView sized to fit and drew each square with a for loop and NSRectFill() (Mac side) for any squares that intersected the dirty rectangle. If you're targeting iOS devices, this is probably not the way to go for performance reasons but for the Mac it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The "Best" can vary depending on what you are comfortable writing, and the size of the matrix you present. Sure, `NSMatrix` would work fine in may cases, but using it and many cells lowers the ceiling of what one *could* accomplish. For a large matrix or high update frequency, you might consider avoiding that higher level abstraction.

Alternatives to `NSMatrix`: The matrix logic is quite easy in this case. Dividing it or the work is also easy, if necessary. Once that logic is implemented, you could either:

- use `CGContextFillRect` (or `NSRectFill`)
- or use a bitmap (e.g. with `CGBitmapContext` to produce an image)

Answer (score 0):

I put together this simple uniform grid class. It is row based and supports different numbers of views per row if required. Adding equal numbers of subviews to each row generates a true uniform grid.

https://github.com/ThesaurusSoftware/TSUniformGrid